# Adding drop down menu to Qt GUI - error 'menubar' no declared

Tags: qt

I'm trying to create a menu in Qt following this example http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/mainwindows-menus.html

but I keep getting the error 'menuBar' not declared in this scope

```
 void Window::createMenus()
 {
     saveMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&Save");


 }
```

In context:

```
 #include <QtGui>

 #include "borderlayout.h"
 #include "window.h"

 Window::Window()
 {
     QTextBrowser *centralWidget = new QTextBrowser;
     //***Change this to whatever widget(s) the drawing area is. QPainter or something?

     centralWidget->setPlainText(tr("DRAW HERE YAY"));

     BorderLayout *layout = new BorderLayout;
     layout->addWidget(centralWidget, BorderLayout::Center);
     layout->addWidget(createLabel("File ..."), BorderLayout::North);
     layout->addWidget(createLabel("Toolbar yo!"), BorderLayout::West);
     //layout->addWidget(createLabel("Status bar"), BorderLayout::South);
     //Maybe we could put in a status bar. For now let's not worry about it. It's not a requirement.
     setLayout(layout);
     createMenus();

     setWindowTitle(tr("Border Layout"));
 }

 QLabel *Window::createLabel(const QString &text)
 {
     QLabel *label = new QLabel(text);
     label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
     return label;
 }

 void Window::createMenus()
 {
     saveMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&Save");


 }
```

window.h

```
 #ifndef WINDOW_H
 #define WINDOW_H

 #include <QWidget>

 class QLabel;
 class QMenu;

 class Window : public QWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     Window();

 private:
     void createMenus();

     QLabel *createLabel(const QString &text);
     QMenu *saveMenu();
 };

 #endif
```

window.cpp

```
 #include <QtGui>

 #include "borderlayout.h"
 #include "window.h"

 Window::Window()
 {
     QTextBrowser *centralWidget = new QTextBrowser;
     //***Change this to whatever widget(s) the drawing area is. QPainter or something?

     centralWidget->setPlainText(tr("DRAW HERE YAY"));

     BorderLayout *layout = new BorderLayout;
     layout->addWidget(centralWidget, BorderLayout::Center);
     layout->addWidget(createLabel("File ..."), BorderLayout::North);
     layout->addWidget(createLabel("Toolbar yo!"), BorderLayout::West);
     //layout->addWidget(createLabel("Status bar"), BorderLayout::South);
     //Maybe we could put in a status bar. For now let's not worry about it. It's not a requirement.
     setLayout(layout);
     createMenus();

     setWindowTitle(tr("Border Layout"));
 }

 QLabel *Window::createLabel(const QString &text)
 {
     QLabel *label = new QLabel(text);
     label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
     return label;
 }

 void Window::createMenus()
 {
     saveMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&Save");


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu bar is a feature of the [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) class.

Because your `Window` class is being inherited directly from [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html), it does not have the `menuBar` method, hence your error.

You need to subclass your `Window` class from `QMainWindow` rather than `QWidget`.

Comment: Hmm ok. I will try changing all my window classes to QMainWindow classes. The Window class inherits from QWidget currently.

Comment: @user1018733: Unless you mean "all my main window classes in all my projects", that's not necessarily a good idea. `QMainWindow` is meant for ... well, the _main_ window. Don't change _all_ the windows in your single application to be main ones, that probably won't make sense.

Comment: Hmm yes it doesn't. What would be the method of adding a menu to this border layout - http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layouts-borderlayout.html

Comment: Have the Window class inherit from QMainWindow instead of QWidget. Since the former inherits directly from the latter, you lose nothing, and you gain all that wonderful main window functionality, like menus, toolbars, icons and so forth.

Comment: Ok I changed the line to 
 class Window : public QMainWindow

Now when I run it. It's an empty window

Comment: @user1018733: I suggest you ask another question on that topic since you'll get more coverage than a conversation with just me in the comments section here. This particular question is answered, I believe, since the problem was subclassing the wrong class. An empty window for a totally different codebase would be better asked separately. It's _possible_ you may have to create a widget within your main window which holds the other controls, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I just stumbled across this because I'm having a similar problem. I believe it's most likely because now you most likely have 2 main window classes and you're adding the menu to the one that isn't shown.